# How do I link an html file with a CSS file if my HTML file is in a sub directory of a subdirectory and my CSS is in the styles folder?

Tags: html, css

I started the Free Code Camp projects, but I can't get the CSS file to link with the HTML and I'm sure that I'm missing something that's right in front of me but I can't figure it out.

Here's the structure of my folders:
the root folder with the index.html,

A folder named site-content,

another named styles,

Images

and Scripts.

In the site-content folder I have another called projects.

In that file I have the tribute.html page.

What I want to do is connect my tribute.css to tribute.html.

Here's how it looks:

`<link href="styles../../../tribute.css" rel="stylesheet">`

or:
`<link href="../../../styles/tribute.css" rel="stylesheet">`
I tried with ../ or even ./, I added from 1 to 5 ../ but it still doesn't work and I am lost.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: A visual representation of your folder hierarchy would be immensely helpful in this case.

Comment: "*I tried with ../ or even ./, I added from 1 to 5 ../ but it still doesn't work and I am lost.*" Can you explain, in your own words, what `./` and `../` represent in this context, respectively? Have you done any research on this method of referring to folders relative to the current file? Are you serving this directory structure with a proper server like Apache? If not, have you considered the difficulties posed by the security mechanisms that prevent most web browsers from traversing local filesystems?

Comment: Yes. So I can't remember the page, I've looked everywhere onlyne on how to do this when it comes to folders,
and I've read that .. is used when you go up a folder. How I just said I've just started trying to learn this from FCC so I am a beginner, if I'd have known the answer I wouldn't have asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood well your file tree look like this:

```
|-index.html
|--site-content-|
|               |--projects--|
|                            |--tribute.html
|
|--styles-------|
|               |--tribute.css
|--Images
|--Scripts
```

From "tribute.html" the path to go to "tribute.css" is "../../styles/tributes.css"

`<link href="../../styles/tribute.css" rel="stylesheet">` should work

I recommand you to do some research about relative and asbolute path to have a better comprehension about it

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Greatly appreciated. I've researched before coming here, but now I understand what I did wrong. Thanks again.